# Building asynchronous client-side includes for non-essential content

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, server-side, client-side

I have several pieces of non-essential content I would like to insert onto several different pages (as part of a series of actions) after a javascript event listener fires.

- Page 1 displays Non-Essential Content A
- Page 2 displays Nothing
- Page 3 displays Non-Essential Content B
- Page 4 displays Non-Essential Content B
- Page 5 displays Non-Essential Content C

All other dimensions of the "insert" are identical - the scripted behaviour of all elements is the same and the CSS styles for all elements are the same - only the HTML markup structure and content differs.

---

**My question is:** *How best to insert the non-essential content?*

**Possible Server-Side Approaches:**

1. Include the content in the document via a server-side language. Reveal the content later by changing the CSS from `display: none` to `display: block`.
2. Don't include the content in the document, but use **Ajax** to go and fetch it from the server, when it is required.

**Possible Client-Side Approaches:**

1. Use `document.write('')` (*Bleagghhh!*)
2. Use an `<iframe>` (*Really?*)
3. Asynchronously load a javascript string and use `.innerHTML`
4. Asynchronously load and parse a javascript object `{}` and use `document.createElement()`, `setAttribute()`, `document.createTextNode`, `.textContent`, `.appendchild()`

---

I feel that using `.innerHTML` (Client-Side:3) is a bit dirty (compared to Client-Side:4), but I've gone with Client-Side:3 anyway:

**Non-Essential Content**

```
var nonEssentialContent = '';
nonEssentialContent += '<h2>Roses are Red...</h2>';
nonEssentialContent += '<p>Roses are red,<br />';
nonEssentialContent += 'Violets are blue,<br />';
nonEssentialContent += 'Client-Side Includes are new to me,<br />';
nonEssentialContent += '<span class="last-line">How about you?</span></p>';
```

**Asynchronously loading Non-Essential Content**

```
var nonEssentialContentScript = document.createElement('script');

function loadMainEvent() {

    [... CODE HERE...]

    containerDiv.innerHTML = nonEssentialContent;

    [... CODE HERE...]

}

function loadNonEssentialContent() {
    nonEssentialContentScript.setAttribute('src', '/path/to/non-essential-content.js');
    document.body.appendChild(nonEssentialContentScript);
    nonEssentialContentScript.addEventListener('load', loadMainEvent, false);
}

loadNonEssentialContent();
```

---

My nagging feeling is, because I am self-taught, I might be missing a really obvious (and superior) approach to building **Client Side Includes**.

I am also concerned that even if the approach above is suitable for a production environment, it may contain a *gotcha* which has not occurred to me.

So, the question above again... ***How best to insert the non-essential content?***

Comment: It's really a matter of taste, the existing structure of your app (if any), your performance requirements, etc etc. Personally I'd rule out document.write and iframe immediately, but otherwise you face a choice of ajax or inserting server-side and then showing/hiding. At a very basic level, that choice could be informed by how much "non-essential" data you have got, how long it takes to load up-front (no ajax) and how often you think users will look at it. ajax calls have a performance and bandwidth overhead. But so does loading data that never gets used.

Comment: So really you have to consider the use cases and decide what you think suits your application and your users, and any constraints under which you may be operating. It's not a question that anyone can definitively answer. The "best" solution is the one that works for your specific situation.

Comment: So I've not missed anything obvious then? I infer from the comment above that Ajax is preferable to inserting a <script> element pointing to a javascript string or a javascript object. What's the advantage? Isn't Ajax excessive to requirements in this setup? (Or are there issues with inserting <script> elements?)

Comment: Nothing wrong with adding script to your page. You could use that to show/hide content, certainly, based on what the user clicks on. Plenty of examples of that around. Like I said, it's a trade-off between the overheads of using ajax (extra HTTP requests) vs the loading large amounts of content automatically which then is never viewed. So it'll depend on the exact nature of your site and the content. Incidentally, just viewed your profile and bio, and surprised you've not dealt with this kind of design decision many times previously?

Comment: It's mostly a matter of taste, I guess.  A few thoughts: - HTML is good at parsing, so innerHTML of a big block of html makes perfect sense. Just mind that newly created html doesn't react to previously defined events. (jQuery .on() method helps).  I would choose innerHTML over document.createElement().  An object as response can be useful if you need to change several elements at once (like form validation)

Comment: Thanks for your perspectives, both of you. @ADyson - I have worked on the web since 1997, but I've never worked with asychronicity before. I'm guessing you came to the web from a development background. I came to the web from a journalistic background. Consequently it has taken me a long time to move over from "the web of documents" to "the web of apps". I only started learning PHP in 2012 and JS in 2013. In December last year I learned Javascript objects, then JSON, then the beginnings of Ajax. I am hoping this will eventually lead to employment, since I have been unemployed since early 2011.

Comment: @Rounin I see well that makes a lot more sense, yes, I take your point. And yes I started as a developer, just as the web was really taking off, so I worked on web apps before almost any other kind, beyond simple command-line stuff. If you have time/resources, it might be worth creating simple prototype applications using different approaches and see which one performs best when you simulate a certain pattern of usage. BTW In the particular scenario you describe, I wouldn't worry too much about the async nature of ajax specifically, it's more just about speed and size of content I think.